# Is there a way to get idToken of an user from Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Im developing a backend for mobile which is using Firebase for authentication and authorization. When the mobile ends the authentication process it sends through http methods to my backend an `idToken` signed by Google, which then I verify the signature and payload of the provided `idtoken`.

Is there a way to get the `idToken` from Google Firebase Console?

At the time I only figured out how to get it from mobile through a method called `getIdToken` for Kotlin. I can't keep getting the token this way, I need to do it without the mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no server-side API to get ID tokens of your users from Firebase Authentication. You will have to get it on the client, and pass it to your server to be verified, exactly as you already seem to be doing.

That is also the process that the Firebase services and SDKs themselves follow, so you might want to reconsider whether this is feasible for your use-case too, or edit your question to better explain why it isn't possible.