# Generate Firebase Verify token on the backend side

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication

We are migrating users to the Firebase and for specific app reasons I need to create a  verify token on the backend side.

So the schema is next -

1. I receive the user email and password from the user. Passing it to
   the backend.
2. Backend generates a verify token, retrieves all the
   info from Firebase, and informs the user.

I'm looking for some way to do it with firebase SDK, but I don't see any option.

Comment: What is a verify token in this context?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen verify ID token. but as I saw here there are no option for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71424592/is-there-a-way-to-get-idtoken-of-an-user-from-firebase-console

Comment: In a trusted environment you can both [create ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and [verify ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) from the clients.